# Editable table but save all values

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Just hit a roadblock, I have a table quite a big table too, and most cells are editable, but I want to click a submit button and save all the values in the all the cells.

Here's what I currently have:

```
 $(".edit").focusout(function(){
        //$("#sub").click(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("editMode");
            var id = this.id;
            var split_id = id.split("_");
            var field_name = split_id[0];
            var edit_id = split_id[1];
            var value = $(this).text();


            $.ajax({
                url: '/claim/store',
                type: 'post',
                data: { field:field_name, value:value, id:edit_id },
                success:function(response){
                    console.log('Save successfully'); 
                }
            });

        });
```

Which works but only does one cell at a time and fo the ajax post I need to send everything through so I can encode it and save to the db.

I have this is a Laravel blade foreach:

```
@foreach($costItems as $key => $cost)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $key }}</td>
                        <td colspan="6">{{ $cost}}</td>
                        <td contentEditable="true" class="edit" id="total_budget_{{ $key }}"></td>
                        <td contentEditable="true" class="edit" id="q1_{{ $key }}"></td>
                        <td contentEditable="true" class="edit" id="q2_{{ $key }}"></td>
                        <td contentEditable="true" class="edit" id="q3_{{ $key }}"></td>
                        <td contentEditable="true" class="edit" id="q4_{{ $key }}"></td>
                        <td contentEditable="true" class="edit" id="q5_{{ $key }}"></td>
                        <td contentEditable="true" class="edit" id="q6_{{ $key }}"></td>
                        <td contentEditable="true" class="edit" id="q7_{{ $key }}"></td>
                        <td contentEditable="true" class="edit" id="q8_{{ $key }}"></td>
                        <td contentEditable="true" class="edit" id="q9_{{ $key }}"></td>
                        <td contentEditable="true" class="edit" id="q10_{{ $key }}"></td>
                        <td contentEditable="true" class="edit" id="q11_{{ $key }}"></td>
                        <td contentEditable="true" class="edit" id="q12_{{ $key }}"></td>
                        <td contentEditable="true" class="edit" id="project_total_{{ $key }}"></td>
                        <td contentEditable="true" class="edit" id="variance_{{ $key }}"></td>
    </tr>
```

Any help greatly appreciated in order to save all the edited values in one go.

Comment: Anyone willing to help me please...?

Comment: Lee_S_666 `$(".edit").focusout` this is not submit button right ??

Comment: No, it's focus out, but I guess I need to push the values into an array or something, but not sure how.

Comment: maybe csv format is good to post server and easy parse !